# Which topics about/in OpenCog could be researched in a Ph.D. thesis

Tags: agi, research, academia, open-cog

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpSmCKe27WE) interview with Lex Fridman and Ben Goertzel, at [2:23:48](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpSmCKe27WE&t=8628s&ab_channel=LexFridman), Lex asks about possibilities for young people in the domain of AGI research. Ben Goertzel then answers that there are various possibilities we can find on the OpenCog framework, including Ph.D. theses.

I was wondering if anyone here knows what exactly he meant when he said we can find Ph.D. theses there? (He said about them at [2:25:18](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpSmCKe27WE&t=145m18s))

(I am considering doing a Ph.D. in AI, so I am interested in finding interesting topics for research)

Comment: Ask your potential PhD advisor.

Comment: I would also formulate this question so that you say that you're looking for people that can really answer this question (i.e. know OpenCog and have e.g. advised PhD students in the past).